# Delegate Help - Using class the delegate is for inside the delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, delegates, protocols

How would I use the class that the delegate is for inside of the protocol methods.

Ex:

```
@protocol ILMIconDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)deleteIcon:(ILMIcon *)icon;
@end

@interface ILMIcon : UIView <IconPopoverViewControllerDelegate>
```

...

```
@end
```

This doesn't work because I can't use `(ILMIcon *)` inside the protocol as it's declared later in the file.
Any help?

Is there any work around, or should I just use `(UIView *)` instead?

Thanks

**Edit:** newacct gave me the answer of using `@class ILMIcon;` before the protocol and it works!
Thanks alot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward-declare the class before the protocol declaration, like:

```
@class ILMIcon;
```